# Target in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, target

Is it possible to make the script work when any equipment is connected? How to do this through target. Code:

```
# Get a device list
$devices = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE (Name LIKE '%Logitech BRIO%' AND Name LIKE '%Phnx MT107a%' AND Name LIKE '%Phnx MT107a%')" | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq 'OK' }
# Select  default camera, microphone, and speakers
foreach ($device in $devices) {
    $deviceName = $device.Name
    if ($deviceName -like '*Logitech BRIO*') {
         # Set the default camera
         [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::WriteByte([System.IntPtr]::Zero, 0x0C, 1)
  } if ($deviceName -like '*Phnx MT107a*') {
         # Set the default microphone
         [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::WriteByte([System.IntPtr]::Zero, 0x0C, 2)
  } if ($deviceName -like '*Phnx MT107a*') {
         # Set the default speakers
         [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::WriteByte([System.IntPtr]::Zero, 0x0C, 3)
  }
}
```

How to do this through target?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: A query like this might get you what you need: `"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Name LIKE '%Logitech BRIO%' OR Name LIKE '%Phnx MT107a%' OR Name LIKE '%Phnx MT107a%' AND Status='OK'"`. So, rather than expecting any single one device to have several names (`AND`) you query for devices matching any of those names (`OR`). Also moved the Status inside the query.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by _target_. Do you mean _event_? Is writing a single byte to fixed memory address `0xC` just a placeholder for the operation you need help with?